# Concatenate multiple Variables/CSVs and export as one CSV file Powershell

Tags: csv, powershell

For example,

I have CSV file and imported to powershell

```
$fullname = Import-Csv “fullname.csv”
$fullname
```

Output is

```
FullName    
------------------
 John      Smith
 Kevin     Johnson
```

I have another CSV file and imported to

```
$Email = Import-Csv “Email.csv”
$Email
```

the output is

```
 Email
-------
jhrjf@gmail.com
hheraf1010@gmail.com
```

I would like to concatenate this 2 variables and export to as one csv file,  so I tried like this

```
 $fullname = Import-Csv “fullname.csv”
        $fullname
    $Email = Import-Csv “Email.csv”
        $Email

($fullname+$Email)|Export-Csv C:\fullnameandEmail.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

i also try like this

```
-join($fullname,$Email)|Export-Csv C:\fullnameandEmail.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

but it was not working,

I would like to make csv like below, how can I concatenate these 2 valuables?

```
FullName                 Email
---------                ----------
John    Smith            jhrjf@gmail.com
Kevin   Johnson          hheraf1010@gmail.com
```

Thank you so much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's helpful to understand that the `$fullname` and `$email` objects you have in memory after importing a CSV are actually arrays of objects.  Each object has one or more properties that represent the column values from the CSV.

You can loop through the objects in either of the arrays and use the Add-Member cmdlet to add a new property to each object.

The following code loops through the `$email` array and for each item, it adds a property with the Email value to the corresponding item in the `$fullname` array. It then exports that merged array to a CSV file.

```
$fullname = Import-Csv "fullname.csv"
$email = Import-Csv "Email.csv"
$i = 0
$email | ForEach-Object { 
    Add-Member -inputobject $fullname[$i] -name Email -value $_.Email -membertype NoteProperty; 
    $i++}
$fullname | Export-Csv -notype -path "C:\fullnameandEmail.csv"
```

Answer (score 2):

So, for simplicity I would combine what the other two have suggested. Use a `For` loop, and then within the loop use `Add-Member`.

```
$fullname = Import-Csv “fullname.csv”
$Email = Import-Csv “Email.csv”
For($i=0;$i -lt $fullname.count;$i++){
    $FullName[$i] | Add-Member 'Email' $Email[$i].email
}
$FullName | Export-CSV -NoType Output.csv
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$names = Import-Csv "fullname.csv"
$emails = Import-Csv "email.csv"

for ( $n = 0; $n -lt $names.Count; $n++ ) {
  New-Object PSObject -Property @{
    "FullName" = $names[$n].FullName
    "Email" = $emails[$n].Email
  } | Select-Object FullName,Email
}
```

Comment: No need for the `Select` statement in what you have there. No need to make whole new objects really.

Comment: Sure, there are multiple ways. Also, the `Select-Object` is in there because the hashtable is not ordered. It's not strictly necessary.